# Determining groups G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group, then $\{(g,g)\mid g\in G \}$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$.

Determine the groups $G$ such that $\{(g,g^{-1})\mid g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$.

I fail to see a case that $\{(g,g^{-1})\mid g\in G \}$ would not be a subgroup of $G\times G$. So wouldn't $G$ be any group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to show that $(g,g^{-1})(h,h^{-1}) = (gh, (gh)^{-1})$ in order for it to be a subgroup. However $(g,g^{-1})(h,h^{-1}) = (gh, g^{-1}h^{-1}) = (gh, (hg)^{-1})$. So to show that it is a subgroup, it is equivalent to showing that $(gh)^{-1} = (hg)^{-1}$.

What happens if you take the inverse of both sides? Do you see what this implies about $G$? (Can you find a counter example from there?)